# I'm having problems with my linkedlist method

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, linked-list

I have implemented this class before, but it is not working. I get an error in the `enqueue(edge)` method. The debugger says head is not empty, but it should be. Can anyone explain why?

This is the code:

```
class eList
{
private:
    class node
    {
    public:
        edge e;
        node * next;

        node(edge x)
        {
            next = NULL;
            e = x;
        }
    };

    node * head, *tail;

    public:
    eList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = head;
    }
```

This is the method where I get the error:

```
    void enqueue(edge component)
    {
        node * bby = new node(component);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = bby;
            tail = head;
        }   
        else
        {
            tail->next = bby;
            tail = bby;
        }
    }
};
```

How this list is used:

```
class edgeTable
{
private:
    //hash table conists of a table of lists
    eList * table;
    //size of table
    int capacity;

    //number of items in hash table
    int numItems;

    int createKey(edge e) {

        unsigned int k1 = e.start->address * 37;
        unsigned int k2 = e.end->address * 37;
        return k1+k2%capacity;
    }
    int createKey(int addss) { return addss%capacity; }

    void resize()
    {
        int oldCap = capacity;
        capacity = capacity * 2;
        edgeTable resized(capacity);

        for (int i = 0; i < oldCap;i++)
            resized.insert(table[i].strct());

        table = resized.table;
    }

    void insert(int key, edge e)
    {
        table[key].enqueue(e);
        numItems++;
    }

public:
    edgeTable()
    {
        capacity = 101;
        table = new eList[capacity];
        numItems = 0;
    }

    edgeTable(int cap)
    {
        capacity = cap;
        table = new  eList[capacity];
        numItems = 0;
    }

    void insert(edge e) 
    { 
        insert(createKey(e), e); 
        if (numItems >= capacity / 2)
            resize();
    }
```

and this class is used for:

```
void addEdge(int x, int y, int w) 
{
    vertex * u = findVertex(x);
    vertex * v = findVertex(y);

    edge e(u,v,w);
    u->edgeList.insert(e);
}
```

EDIT: added supplemental code.

Comment: Could you show more code, e.g. how you use your list?

Comment: @JBL added more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't add comment for now so i'm answer, take it like comment.

the `void enqueue(edge component)` really is no problem with it but i think you'r problem in `void insert(edge e)` with `insert(createKey(e), e);` especially `createKey(e)` .

in `createKey`  `k1+k2%capacit` not equal to `(k1+k2)%capacity` 
you want this or not? because is key it's mean is index to array and maybe return wrong index!

sorry need 50/50 to comment!

Comment: I will check the code, because I hadn't seen that oversight. Thanks. I'll report when I can check it.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thank you.